# My MailApp won't send any emails GoogleScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am trying to send an email to the admin of a certain Department which is in a certain sheet. Everything goes smoothly exept the mail never sends. My script does a bit more then just sending mail but ill but exactly my code. By the way this is my first experience with google script so feel free to improve my script.

```
function onEdit(event) 
{
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = s.getActiveRange();

  var completerPar = s.getRange(r.getRow(),9);
  var completerQuand = s.getRange(r.getRow(),10);

  if(r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue() == true) 
  {
    if ( s.getName() == "RepFormulaireDemande")
    {
      var row = r.getRow();
      r.setValue(false);
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();  
      var range = s.getRange(row,3);   
      var Departement = range.getDisplayValue();
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(Departement);
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      range = s.getRange(row,7);

      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).setBackgroundRGB(0,255, 0);
      r.setValue("Envoyé");

      //avertissement à l'administrateur de département
      s = ss.getSheetByName("Administrateurs");
      var column = 2
      range = s.getRange(1,column);
      while (range.getDisplayValue() != Departement)
      {
        column += 1
        range = s.getRange(1,column);
      }
      range = s.getRange(2,column);
      for (var x = 3 ; x - 2 <= range.getDisplayValue(); x++)
      {  
        var emailRange = s.getRange(x,column);
        var emailAdresse = emailRange.getDisplayValue();
        var message = "La page " + Departement + " du HelpDesk a été mise à jour!;
        var subject = "HelpDesk" + Departement;
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAdresse,subject,message);
      } 
    }
    else if(completerPar.getValue() !== "" && completerQuand.getValue() !== "")
    {
      var row = r.getRow();
      r.setValue("fini");
      var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();  
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completer");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).setBackgroundRGB(255, 255, 255);
      s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
      s.deleteRow(row);
      var delai = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 11);
      row = targetSheet.getLastRow();
      delai.setValue('=IF(DAYS(J' + row + '; $A' + row + ') = 1;DAYS(J' + row + '; $A' + row + ') &  " jour"; DAYS(J' + row + '; $A' + row + ') & " jours")' );
    }
    else
    {
      r.setValue(false);
    }
  }
}

*yes my script has some french in it sorry*
```

Comment: You may have exceeded the quota.  It's also possible that sending an email requires permissions and so you may have to use an installable onedit trigger.

Comment: Your code has an unterminated string in it.  Check it in the Script Editor. Also it's quite involved for an onEdit() perhaps you're just running out of time as you only have 30 seconds for simple triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but if you use a [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) you will not be able to send emails as the [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) say:

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
>   simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
>   authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the
>   Language service, which is anonymous.

As a workaround, you could use an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions), but also taking into consideration its [Restriction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions) for sending mails:

> Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who
>   created them. For example, if you create an installable open trigger,
>   it runs when your colleague opens the document (if your colleague has
>   edit access), but it runs as your account. This means that if you
>   create a trigger to send an email when a document is opened, the email
>   is always be sent from your account, not necessarily the account that
>   opened the document. However, you could create an installable trigger
>   for each account, which would result in one email sent from each
>   account.

Now, for setting up the installable trigger, do the following:

1) Go to your Apps Script project

2) Click Edit->Current project's triggers

3) Click "+ Add Trigger"

4) Select :

Choose which function to run -> `Function Name`

Select event source-> From spreadsheet

Select event type -> On edit

5) Click Save

I hope this can help you and the triggers' restrictions will not affect you that much.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution worked! I just needed to change my simple onEdit trigger to make sure nothing was being doubled and now it works marvellously!

Comment: @JordanCôté. I'm glad my solution worked for you, please consider accept my answer as the correct answer. [How to accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)